# Oracle db separated schemas for one user

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, schema

in MySQL I would type `create schema;` and then `use schema;` as the same user, what is the equivalent in Oracle? In Oracle new schema means new user? I'd like to separate some tables for one user without creating new user.

For example:

```
a.products
a.users
a.roles
b.customers
b.buildings
c.offers
```

etc.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You would have to have separate users to have separate schemas; but why do you want/need the seperation? Security, logical separation, duplicate object names, something else?

Comment: I have one schema for my application where i store data about it. But I need my users to be allowed create some tables and run dml on it. I'd like to separate these tables from my application schema. For example, user will create schema A and create 5 tables in it, then create schema B and create other 5 tables in it. Then user choose schema and run some dml statements. But he can't choose my application schema of course. I think it is special application.